# How to retrieve values between two strings

Tags: python, json

I have a json file. I want to retrieve values between two strings using python.

```
{
    "101": {

        "set": [
            "1012", 
            "some text a."
        ], 
        "tag": "tagtext"
    }, 
    "1027": {
        "slide": [
            "1013757", 
            "x"
        ]
    }, 
    "1014220": {
        "set": [
            "1018420", 
            "some text."
        ], 
        "ans": "4th"
    }, 
    "1019660": {
        "set": [
            "1031920", 
            "Some text b"
        ], 
        "tag": "tagtext"
    }, 
    "1034280": {
        "set": [
            "1040560", 
            "some text"
        ], 
        "interact": "intertext"
    },
```

I want to extract data between **set** and **tag**:

The output should be:
"some text a."
"some text b."

Comment: This is almost exactly the [canonical example of asking about your attempted solution instead of the actual problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You don't want to extract the data between "set" and "tag"; if you tried that, you would get all sorts of extra cruft and incorrect data. What you need is a JSON parser.

Answer (score 1):

Parse the input as JSON and check if a `tag` exists.

```
import json

with open("j.json") as f:
    j = json.load(f)

for k, v in j.items():
    try:
        s = v["set"]
        t = v["tag"]
        print(s[1])
    except:
        # no tag
        pass
```

Output:

```
some text a.
Some text b
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse `json` and convert that in `dict`. In `dict` you can check for keys. If both  keys exist then you can print the data.

If you want, I can give code for that. But better you try your self, otherwise I will help.

Answer (score 0):

A few improvment:

1. You can't know if he want's to print or use the values so I've wrapped it in a function
2. You can't know for sure that *set* key will contain only two values, since he requested the last value using [-1] is better.
3. If you want to use exception catch only **KeyError** and not all the exception, personally I prefer using **if** as it clearer but this is a matter of style

   ```
   import json

   with open("j.json") as f:
       j = json.load(f)

   def search(j):
        ret = []
        for k, v in j.items():
            if v.get('set') and v.get('tag'):
                ret.append(v['set'][-1])
        return ret
   search(j)
   ```

*[u'some text a.', u'Some text b']*